# facebook real time updates notification intermittent

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, real-time-updates

I have a Facebook app with real time update subscription. Users authorize my app and we receive notifications from Facebook when those users upload photos to Facebook.

It was working fine until early December 2013. Then we get notification for only some users. I have checked the users access token and I couldn't see any pattern as why it would work for some an not others. There are about 300 users who authorized the app thus I think the volume of notification is quite negligible.

Is there a limit on notification or number of users? 
Is there any kind or renewal needed from our users to keep receiving notification? I don't believe that is the case since the missed notifications happen to both old and new users.
Any other limitation we should be aware of?